# How to manage multiple stylessheets and make the app efficient

Tags: css, angular, sass

I'm using Angular+2 with bootstrap 4.3.X and I want to re-style/re-theme the bootstrap scss.
I want to achieve this the best way with Angular.

I'm aware this may be done with scss only.

```
[scss only]
angular.json
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
styles.scss
            $theme-colors: (  "primary": #f700ff );
            @import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
            ...
```

But what i'm trying to achieve is below.

```
[Angular way]
angular.json
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"
            ],
styles.scss
            $theme-colors: (  "primary": #f700ff );
            ...
```

But it does not seem to matter which order i enter in angular.json. The $theme-colors simply won't work.

The two options work very differently. [scss only] is slow, the whole bootstrap module needs to be re-compiled if any component is changed. While in [Angular way] it never re-compiles during debug, only during build process.

Also

```
[scss only] ng build --prod -> dist= 2,99MB
[Angular way] ng build --prod -> dist = 2,11MB
```

Please help providing what is missing to do it the [Angular way].
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a `variables.scss` file in which you declare `theme-colors`, add that to your

```
      "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": [""]
      },
```

in angular.json configurations

Then in `styles.scss` at the top declare `@import 'variables.scss'` then you can use the `$theme-colors` var in your stylesheets. in every stylesheet you need the variables you need to declare the import statement.

Comment: Hello Sjoerd, thanks for your answer.

Unfortunately I'm still not getting it.

I've tried doing it with a variables.scss (even though i would believe the variables.scss file itself would a good practice, but not required). Including it in angular.json and importing it to styles.scss and other stylesheets. But "primary" remains blue, unless I actually import bootstrap via scss import which I do not want to. Maybe there is something i'm missing.